# Using __declspec(dllimport) in a class containing a static member of its own type

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, dllimport

I have a class which header looks like this:

```
class MYCLASS_DECLSPEC MyClass
{
    MyClass(int x);

    ....

    static const MyClass Zero;
}
```

On the implementation file I initialized the static const member:

```
const A A::Zero(0);
```

Now I want to compile this code sometimes as a DLL and sometimes as static library. The common practice is to define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC like this:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_MYDLL
#define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

When I compile this code as DLL (with BUILDING_MYDLL defined) everything is working fine. But when I compile this code as static library (without BUILDING_MYDLL defined) I get the following error:

```
error: definition of static data member 'MyClass::Zero' of dllimport'd class
```

If I totally remove the __declspec(dllimport) the code compiles successfully as a static library.

I'm using mingw32 compiler on Windows 7.

Can someone explain why it happens and how to solve it?

Comment: The preprocessor symbol `BUILDING_MYDLL` doesn't toggle between DLL and static library. It toggles the meaning of `MYCLASS_DECLSPEC` to either export a symbol (when building the DLL) or import a symbol, when compiling a client linking against that DLL. Since your mental model is flawed I don't know what to make of this question. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, I know the symbol `BUILDING_MYDLL` toggles the `MYCLASS_DECLSPEC`. The makefile should define `BUILDING_MYDLL` for compiling as a DLL or not define it to compile as a static library. What do you mean by "mental model is flawed"? What information is missing in my question to make it more clear?

Comment: If `BUILDING_MYDLL` is not defined you are **not** building a static library, but rather client code **importing** symbols from the DLL. See [Importing and Exporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h658af8.aspx) to understand, what your code really does.

Comment: I read some more and I think I'm starting to get the idea. But I still don't understand what `__declspec(dllimport)` is used for: let's say I'm building a shared library; So I'd like to export classes/methods using `__declspec(dllexport)`, so what is the need of the common practice of using ifdef: `#ifdef BUILDING_MYDLL #define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport) #else #define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport) #endif`

Comment: The `__declspec(dllimport)` is for the *client*, the application that is *using* your library.  If you are building (or using) a static library, you need to define `MYCLASS_DECLSPEC` to an empty string.  Static libraries don't use `__declspec`.

Comment: So how should I use `__declspec(dllimport)`? Say I write an application that uses an already compiled shared library (DLL or SO), where should I put `__declspec(dllimport)`?

Answer (score 0):

I would think we put #defines in another #define:

```
#ifdef _DLL
#ifdef BUILDING_MYDLL
#define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define MYCLASS_DECLSPEC
#endif
```